# how to retrieve a part of a bitmapdata which is in a particular color

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bitmapdata which contains two colors in it say black and white. Now the black area is transparent and the white area is visible. Now the image should be clickable only on the white areas and not on the black transparent area. How can we do this?

PS: The white areas are not in a regular locations I mean they are in random locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
//add listener for mouse clicks
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventHandler);

function eventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //1x1 bitmapData to store snapshot
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1, 1);
    //matrix object to 'move' stage so that pixel under mouse is effectively at 0,0
    var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    //'move' stage according to mouse x,y values
    matrix.translate(-event.stageX, -event.stageY);
    //take snapshot of stage
    bmd.draw(stage, matrix);
   //get colour from snapshot data
   var pixel:uint = bmd.getPixel(0, 0);
   //trace result
   trace("colour = "+pixel.toString(16));
}
```

Taken from http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/06/get-pixel-colour-below-mouse-pointer/

Edit because I have time:

So in your case, instead of:

```
trace("colour = "+pixel.toString(16));
```

You would use:

```
if(pixel.toString(16) == "ffffff") // if clicked pixel is white
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sam's answer is great, but since you say you know that the pixel in question is part of a bitmapdata you could skip taking a snapshot of the stage and just check the bitmapdata directly instead. I think it could be as simple as:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventHandler);

function eventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if (myBitmapData.getPixel(event.stageX, event.stageY) == 0xffffff)
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Also if you want to take alpha into consideration you will want to use [getPixel32()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32%28%29) instead of getPixel().